# Mongodb - Returning the points nearest to a location, with distance

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spatial

What is the MongoDB's equivalent to this query:

```
SELECT 111151.29341326 * SQRT( pow(-6.186753-`Latitude`, 2) 
                               + pow(106.772835-`Longitude`, 2)
                                 * cos(-6.186753*0.017453292519943)
                                 * cos(`Latitude`*0.017453292519943)
                             )
       as distance
from tablename ;
```

This uses the [haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to compute the great-circle distance to a fixed point. We want to get nearest 20 points from a location and then display the distance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MongoDB has built in support for geoindexing.  You don't need to do the calculation yourself.

Basically, you would create a field with the lat/long stored as an array or as sub documents, something like one of these:

```
{ loc : [ 50 , 30 ] } //SUGGESTED OPTION
{ loc : { x : 50 , y : 30 } }
{ loc : { lon : 40.739037, lat: 73.992964 } }
```

Then index the new loc field appropriately:

```
db.places.ensureIndex( { loc : "2d" } )
```

Finally you can then use one of the operators to query a point for the nearest 20 results:

```
db.places.find( { loc : { $near : [50,50] } } ).limit(20)
```

You could, of course, just use MongoDB to store the data, then pull the information out of the DB with a find() and do the calculation client-side but I imagine that is not what you want to do.

If the distance part of the equation is what you want:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-geoNearCommand

The $geoNear operator will return the distance also.  An example:

```
> db.runCommand( { geoNear : "places" , near : [50,50], num : 10 } );
{
        "ns" : "test.places",
        "near" : "1100110000001111110000001111110000001111110000001111",
        "results" : [
                {
                        "dis" : 69.29646421910687,
                        "obj" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("4b8bd6b93b83c574d8760280"),
                                "y" : [
                                        1,
                                        1
                                ],
                                "category" : "Coffee"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "dis" : 69.29646421910687,
                        "obj" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("4b8bd6b03b83c574d876027f"),
                                "y" : [
                                        1,
                                        1
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "stats" : {
                "time" : 0,
                "btreelocs" : 1,
                "btreelocs" : 1,
                "nscanned" : 2,
                "nscanned" : 2,
                "objectsLoaded" : 2,
                "objectsLoaded" : 2,
                "avgDistance" : 69.29646421910687
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

The `"dis" : 69.29646421910687` elements are what you are looking for, there is also a spherical distance option.

For all this, how to use the distances, and more, take a look here for more information on geo indexes and how to use them:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing/

Comment: I understand that already. But I want the return result to contain "distance" field. How to achieve that?

Comment: I don't think you read the page I linked - I expanded the answer to include the operators that return distance, they are just further down the page

Comment: What about if the additional column we want to have is not distance but something else?

Comment: "something else" is too vague to answer, if you want generic calculation then Map/Reduce or the Aggregation Framework in 2.2

Comment: In MySQL you can add columns to the result you want, usually based on formula. If the table has 4 columns you can get a view with 6 columns. Can you do that on mongodb? Looks like you need to get the data and compute the columns your self. I am just trying to make sure.

Comment: There are options in the aggregation framework in 2.2 to do projections as you describe, or you can calculate on the client side and insert, but that is a completely different question to the one you actually asked - that is not mentioned at all - I would recommend asking that, in detail, separately

Comment: can you help with the distanceMultiplier option in geoNear command. The mongo documentation on this topic is very minimal. I wanted the distance back in Km's

Comment: you should ask a proper question, not comment, but here's a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5322746/1148648